# t-sql subquery and groupby

Tags: t-sql, subquery

Under the my query.I select this way all job count by fullname.

```
SELECT COUNT(sy.FullName)                        [Count Job],
       sy.FullName                               [FullName],
       MIN(CAST(i.vrp_notificationdate AS DATE)) [Oldest Date]
FROM   BusinessUnit AS b
       INNER JOIN SystemUser AS sy
         ON b.BusinessUnitId = sy.BusinessUnitId
       INNER JOIN Incident AS i
         ON i.OwnerId = sy.SystemUserId
GROUP  BY f.sy.FullName
```

This query show this table

> ```
> ---------------------------------
> Count Job   FullName  Oldest Date
>   10           a       2011-10-11
>   20           B       2011-10-11
>   55           C       2011-10-11
> ---------------------------------
> ```

But i want to make under table for example.

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> Count Job   FullName  Oldest Date      Open Job         Close Job
>   10           A       2011-10-11         5                5  
>   20           B       2011-10-11         13               7 
>   55           C       2011-10-11         48               7
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

I have status of columnname on my Incident Table,if status code is 5 that the job is closed.when i used group by condition statuscode,then table is under .And i dont want show this showing table.

> ```
> ---------------------------------
> Count Job   FullName  Oldest Date
>   10           a       2011-10-11
>   13           B       2011-10-11
>   48           C       2011-10-11
>   7            B       2011-10-11
>   7            C       2011-10-11
> ---------------------------------
> ```

when i use union on my t-sql,i take this error "all queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

how to exactly solve this query.Any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the query but it is invalid. It has 2 `GROUP BY` clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using CASE and SUM?

```
SELECT COUNT(sy.FullName)                        [Count Job],
       sy.FullName                               [FullName],
       MIN(CAST(i.vrp_notificationdate AS DATE)) [Oldest Date],

       SUM(CASE i.status 
             WHEN 5 THEN 1
             ELSE 0)                             [Open Jobs],

       SUM(CASE i.status 
            WHEN 5 THEN 0
            ELSE 1)                              [Closed Jobs]

FROM   BusinessUnit AS b
       INNER JOIN SystemUser AS sy
         ON b.BusinessUnitId = sy.BusinessUnitId
       INNER JOIN Incident AS i
         ON i.OwnerId = sy.SystemUserId
GROUP  BY f.sy.FullName
```

Comment: thanks @Gustav,i didnt know how to handle case when.Again thanks.

Comment: When all else fails, try reading the manual :) [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)